# Solr optimize too frequently?

Tags: solr

We have 16 core on a server, each of them has 4.5 millions customer orders. Recently, we commit 200 new orders into each core per hour, then optimize all cores. We find that every optimize operation need 30min at least. I have several questions:

1. We should optimize after every commit? Would it decrease query performance significantly in our circumstance if we optimize per day?
2. We only add new orders into solr, will never update or delete any one in solr. So ,can we only optimize the index which we commit, in other word, can we optimize index by date range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, do not optimize after every commit.  The frequency with which you should optimize is dependent on how often you update.

From http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Optimization_Considerations

> If you have a rapidly changing index, rather than optimizing, you
>   likely simply want to use a lower merge factor. Optimizing is very
>   expensive, and if the index is constantly changing, the slight
>   performance boost will not last long. The tradeoff is not often worth
>   it for a non static index.

The question of "will it decrease query performance significantly" is something you'll have to test for yourself, but measure, measure, measure.  Then, decide if the performance is actually a problem.  If a 50ms query becomes a 60ms query, that's a 20% increase in response time, but does it matter?  Only you can answer those tradeoffs.  But you MUST have numbers.

Comment: Why lower merge factor is better than optimize for rapidly changing index? Can you give me more imformation?

Answer (score 0):

You should commit in batches and optimize in intervals. 
As optimize is a very heavy operation where the index segments are combined to form a single segment to improve performance.

However, with the latest Lucene you may not even need to use the [Optimize](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#optimize%28%29).
The optimize has been deprecated with the latest versions :-

> This method has been deprecated, as it is horribly inefficient and
>   very rarely justified. Lucene's multi-segment search performance has
>   improved over time, and the default TieredMergePolicy now targets
>   segments with deletions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not know well about Lucene. I just downloaded solr and deployed on our server. I'm using solr 4.0 that released just before a month. Does it contain the change you said?

Comment: The Changes are available with the Current lucene release and would be packaged with solr.